# Question migration—error terminology

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm a mod on Academia, and someone recently posted the following question:

> [What's the difference between fault, error and defect?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7358/73)

Would this be on-topic here?

Comment: We already have a [similar question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37029/difference-between-defect-and-bugtesting/) - so whilst it would seem on-topic it might be closed if migrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Deco](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42031/deco) [said](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/question-migrationerror-terminology#comment13773_5471), there is a similar question, [Difference between a defect and a bug in testing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37029/difference-between-defect-and-bugtesting/) where one of the answers gives the definitions of *error*, *faults*, and *failures* given by the IEEE Standards. As the questions on Academia doesn't have any answer, migrating it on Programmers would have just the effect of closing it, without even the possibility of merging them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we can close as duplicate if it's migrated.

Comment: Just checked. We can close as a duplicate post-migration without rejecting the migration. This would allow us to point this question toward ones that have high quality answers.

Comment: [Migrations are not rejected if the question is closed as exact duplicate, or as belonging to another site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/140449). That is not the issue. As far as I see, the only cases where a closed question is migrated to another site is when the same user asked the same exact question, possibly to merge the answers of both the questions. The migration is not used as way to say to the OP "See? The next time you can ask your question there." At least, it is not when the question is then closed as duplicate of a question asked from another user. `:)`

Comment: If the question is off-topic on the site where asked and on-topic, I feel it should be migrated and have informed the Academics mods. Either it will remain open as a unique question, have answers merged, or be closed as an exact duplicate and people searching can use that duplicate as a signpost to find the original question and its answers. Any of those outcomes is a good thing.

Comment: @ThomasOwens and kiamlaluno, although dupe closures don't reject the migration FWIW [deleting a merge stub rejects the migration](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5470/25936).

Comment: @ThomasOwens - Thanks, just sent it over.